# Formula to calculate saturation parameters of a power transformer?

Tags: voltage, current, transformer, saturation, magnetic-flux

I have recently learnt to build power transformers, my requirement is to make primary core reach right below saturation. I researched on google and found that load current has nothing to do with the saturation of the primary core. I am building an isolation transformer and expecting 230 volts at secondary.

My question is, what core size and number of turns should I choose for primary? so that primary core reaches right below saturation, so that primary core will be full of flux and cannot accommodate any more flux.

If I want to feed 230 volts to primary, should I choose primary core size and number of turns for 200 volts and feed the primary with over voltage than rated voltage? Will this make primary core reach (right below) saturation?

If I increase turns and decrease core area, will it make the core reach saturation?

Please clear my doubts as I don't seem to find clear answers on various blogs and PDFs on google.

Comment: Saturation isn't black and white so, trying to design a core that runs just below saturation is not understanding how cores saturate.

Comment: Reading this may help you somewhat: https://www.electrical4u.com/core-of-transformer-and-design-of-transformer-core/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I want to feed 230 volts to primary, should I choose primary core size and number of turns for 200 volts and feed the primary with over voltage than rated voltage? Will this make primary core reach (right below) saturation?

The transformer will already be designed to be close to saturation. But the answer is yes. By over-volting it you are getting closer to saturation (or may be fully saturated). This is using up the safety margin designed in to the original product. This does not seem like a good thing to do. Saturation is considered a bad thing for power transformers. Something to be avoided.

> If I increase turns and decrease core area, will it make the core reach saturation?

Reducing core cross-section area will push the core toward or into saturation. Adding turns will move the core away from saturation. Again I want to emphasize that people usually try to avoid core saturation.

Comment: Adding turns to a core will reduce saturation due to the inductance of the primary increasing. Inductance rises as turns squared whereas H field (which drives saturation) rises as ampere-turns but given that inductance increases reduce operating current, more turns equals less saturation.

Comment: @Andyaka While increasing turns does increase inductance, it's not the best way to describe why it moves you away from saturation. Increasing turns increases the volt.second product that the core is able to support. Flux has units of volt.seconds, the relationship is right there. Going via inductance (which changes depending on whether a core is saturated or not) is a harmful to understanding, especially with a clueless noob like the OP.

Comment: @Andyaka Consider what happens when you gap the core. I knew an experienced engineer who was confused about this. It wasn't until I pointed out the volt.second product that he realised that an adjustable gap inductor still had the same voltage rating (to first order for modest gaps), even as it produced variable inductance.

Comment: Neil we've discussed this before and I prefer my explanation.

Comment: @Neil_UK In his defense (not that he needs me to defend him) Andy was probably trying to explain it to me, not the OP. And for historical reasons, this might make sense.

Comment: @Andyaka so to confirm i should do the windings for 200 volts and feed 230 volts to make primary core reach near saturation, correct? Another question is, what is the way to check that transformer has reached near saturation without oscilloscope? so that it can be turned off to prevent thermal damage.

Comment: Read my comment under your question @Yogie and please note that I am not making an answer other than what I've said in that comment.